# How to block ip adresses which access more than n-pages in m-prediod of time?

Tags: centos, webserver

How to block IP adresses which access more than n pages in m period of time?
I want to block all auto-traffic and I am not sure how to approach this issue.

Comment: The answer could probably involve involve [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/), which can monitor logfiles and dynamically add and later remove iptable rules depending on the results, though many of the tutorials you'll find probably deal with avoiding brute-force login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I moved my entire site (name-based VHosts) to SSL and redirect every Request with HTTP 301 "Moved permanently". This had the benefit of having a much much simpler apache-config (one 100 line file) AND most spammers / bots are completely gone. Apparently the don't manage the redirect or SSL.

And your users data is protected!